# Google analitics API - organic search values for list of pages

Tags: google-analytics-api

How can i get organic search values for list of pages at once , from GA API for some time period ?

For example , i want to get something like this :

1. htpp://example.com/page1 - 4324
2. htpp://example.com/page2 - 3123
3. htpp://example.com/page3 - 43

Comment: The [Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) will help you construct the query. For the code to code authenticate with and query the api, Google your coding language and Google Analytics api.